# Display the username in a custom block

Tags: nodes, display-suite

I'm using D7 and I have a custom content type (Client) and I have a custom select list field for the User entity displayed in a custom block.

I have a custom display layout for the *Client* content type, wherein all fields are displayed in different blocks using Display Suite. The user's name is displayed only when the user field is enabled in the node main content, else it remains blank.

How do I display the username in the block without the need to keep the field enabled in another part of the node view?

Answer (score -1):

try with arguments or use views module and configure your block view CONTEXTUAL FILTERS

Comment: I am using the contextual filters. It displays other fields related to the node, but not the Username.

Comment: what's the relation between node and user name ?

Comment: The username is the user who is the point of contact for the client. Each Client has a separate point of contact, User